# Create a custom UI widget with custom constructors

Tags: flutter, dart, constants

Looking to create a custom button in flutter that is based on the `CupertioButton`.

the end result should be looking like this:

```
MainCustomButton.success(label: 'ok', onPressed: (){});
MainCustomButton.danger(label: 'delete', onPressed: (){});
```

with each of the 'clones' have it's custom styles applied.

This is the code I have been messing with but I couldn't go further than this:

```
class MainCustomButton extends StatefulWidget {
    MainCustomButton.success({
        Key? key,
    }) : super(key: key);

    MainCustomButton.danger({
        Key? key,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<MainCustomButton> createState() => _MainCustomButtonState();
}

class _MainCustomButtonState extends State<MainCustomButton> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CupertinoButton(child: Text('click me'), onPressed: () {});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is using [custom constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors):

```
class MainCustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainCustomButton({Key? key, required this.label}) : super(key: key);

  final String label;

  const MainCustomButton.success({super.key, this.label = 'ok'});

  const MainCustomButton.danger({super.key, this.label = 'delete'});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoButton(
      child: Text(label),
      onPressed: () {},
    );
  }
}
```

And the final result:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [
          MainCustomButton.success(),
          MainCustomButton.danger(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create 2 constructors for 1 `StatefulWidget`. You can create a class and make static functions instead that returns you a widget.

Example:

```js
class MainButton{
  static Widget success({required String label, required VoidCallback ontap}){
  return CupertinoButton(child: Text(label), onPressed: ontap);
 }

 static Widget danger({required String label, required VoidCallback ontap}){
  return CupertinoButton(child: Text(label), onPressed: ontap);
 }
}
```